# Track execution time per task in gradle script?

Tags: gradle

What is the most elegant way to track the execution times on how long a task took in a gradle build script? In an optimal case, log the time directly same or next line to the task name:

```
:buildSrc:testClasses (0.518 secs)
:fooBar (28.652 secs)
```

Comment: If you run gradle with the `--profile` parameter, it generates a report in `build/reports/profile` with task execution times in it...  Is that good enough?

Comment: That's a nice report, but requires an extra step in gathering all build related information, optimally the person analysing our Jenkins gradle jobs can see the execution time directly inline. Thx anyways!

Comment: @tim_yates I've expanded your `--profile` comment into a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68719009/1108305

Comment: @M.Justin nice 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to implement a [TaskExecutionListener](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html) (I'm sure you can handle that part) and register it with `gradle.taskGraph.addTaskExecutionListener`.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a great fit, the only thing I am still missing is how to register the listener for all tasks.

Comment: You just need to register a single listener, once.

Answer (score 100):

Just to elaborate on [Peter Niederwieser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032086/2911458): We wanted to do the same thing, as well as a report timings at the end of the
build, so slow steps are obvious (and appropriate parties feel a small but healthy bit of shame when they slow down the build!).

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 37.973 secs
Task timings:
    579ms  :myproject-foo:clean
  15184ms  :myproject-bar:clean
   2839ms  :myproject-bar:compileJava
  10157ms  :myproject-bar:jar
    456ms  :myproject-foo:compileJava
    391ms  :myproject-foo:libs
    101ms  :myproject-foo:jar
    316ms  :myproject-bar:compileTestJava
    364ms  :myproject-foo:compileTestJava
  53353ms  :myproject-foo:test
   2146ms  :myproject-bar:test
   8348ms  :www/node:npmInstall
    687ms  :www/node:npmTest
```

Something like the code below can be dropped into your top level `build.gradle` to report timings during execution, or after completion.

```
// Log timings per task.
class TimingsListener implements TaskExecutionListener, BuildListener {
    private Clock clock
    private timings = []

    @Override
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        clock = new org.gradle.util.Clock()
    }

    @Override
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState taskState) {
        def ms = clock.timeInMs
        timings.add([ms, task.path])
        task.project.logger.warn "${task.path} took ${ms}ms"
    }

    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        println "Task timings:"
        for (timing in timings) {
            if (timing[0] >= 50) {
                printf "%7sms  %s\n", timing
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void buildStarted(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void settingsEvaluated(Settings settings) {}
}

gradle.addListener new TimingsListener()
```

Comment: Is there any way this could be like a plugin or something that I could easily add to a build script without polluting the script? Or are there any other ways to do this timing in a more clean fashion? Thank you!

Comment: Can it somehow show the total time, including the installation time (to the device/emulator) of the app?

Comment: `timing[0] >= 50` gives me an annoying warning _'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'_ so I added an ignore `//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck` above the conditional

Answer (score 30):

This is a variation of [jlevy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438620/2350083) which has been modified to remove the usage of the publicly accessible gradle `Clock` class, which has been deprecated.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 37.973 secs
Task timings:
    579ms  :myproject-foo:clean
  15184ms  :myproject-bar:clean
   2839ms  :myproject-bar:compileJava
  10157ms  :myproject-bar:jar
    456ms  :myproject-foo:compileJava
    391ms  :myproject-foo:libs
    101ms  :myproject-foo:jar
    316ms  :myproject-bar:compileTestJava
    364ms  :myproject-foo:compileTestJava
  53353ms  :myproject-foo:test
   2146ms  :myproject-bar:test
   8348ms  :www/node:npmInstall
    687ms  :www/node:npmTest
```

Something like the code below can be dropped into your top level `build.gradle` to report timings during execution, or after completion.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
// Log timings per task.
class TimingsListener implements TaskExecutionListener, BuildListener {
    private long startTime
    private timings = []

    @Override
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime()
    }

    @Override
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState taskState) {
        def ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        timings.add([ms, task.path])
        task.project.logger.warn "${task.path} took ${ms}ms"
    }

    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        println "Task timings:"
        for (timing in timings) {
            if (timing[0] >= 50) {
                printf "%7sms  %s\n", timing
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void settingsEvaluated(Settings settings) {}
}

gradle.addListener new TimingsListener()
```

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, but I've found a cool plugin that does task timing. It's like [@jlevy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438620/2911458), but with some more options available: https://github.com/passy/build-time-tracker-plugin

This plugin by Pascal Hartig continuously logs your build times and provides CSV and bar chart summaries. The developer recommends it for monitoring your build times over time, versus `--profile` which gives you a snapshot for the current build.

This is how I'm currently using it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:gradle-plugin:0.7.+"
    }
}

apply plugin: "build-time-tracker"

buildtimetracker {
    reporters {
        summary {
            ordered false
            threshold 50
            barstyle 'unicode'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`--profile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_performance) flag will generate a profile report.  The generated HTML file includes a "Task Execution" tab which contains the per-task timings.

```
$ gradle build --profile

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 21s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed

See the profiling report at: file:///path/to/gs-spring-boot/complete/build/reports/profile/profile-2021-08-09-16-22-40.html
A fine-grained performance profile is available: use the --scan option.
```

This is documented in the online [Command-Line Interface documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_performance)

> Generates a high-level performance report in the `$buildDir/reports/profile` directory. `--scan` is preferred.

### Task Execution output

> | Task | Duration | Result |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | : | 20.046s | (total) |
> | :compileJava | 9.221s |  |
> | :test | 6.492s |  |
> | :compileTestJava | 3.161s |  |
> | :bootJarMainClassName | 0.813s |  |
> | :bootJar | 0.338s |  |
> | :jar | 0.017s |  |
> | :processResources | 0.003s | NO-SOURCE |
> | :classes | 0.001s | Did No Work |
> | :assemble | 0s | Did No Work |
> | :build | 0s | Did No Work |
> | :check | 0s | Did No Work |
> | :processTestResources | 0s | NO-SOURCE |
> | :testClasses | 0s | Did No Work |

### Gradle build scan

The `--profile` option and its documentation both recommend using the `--scan` option to generate a [build scan](https://gradle.com/gradle-enterprise-solution-overview/build-scan-root-cause-analysis-data/).  This generates a scan and publishes it to [scans.gradle.com](https://scans.gradle.com).  In addition to transmitting your build details to the Gradle build scan external service, this requires accepting the [Gradle Terms of Service](https://gradle.com/terms-of-service).

```
$ gradle build --scan

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service.
Do you accept these terms? [yes, no] yes

Gradle Terms of Service accepted.

Publishing build scan...
https://gradle.com/s/5u4w3gxeurtd2
```

#### Scan output

> **61 tasks executed in 4 projects in 7s, with 10 avoided tasks saving 4.231s**
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | :buildSrc:compileKotlin | 3.584s |
> | :app:test | 0.745s |
> | :list:test | 0.742s |
> | :list:compileJava | 0.062s |
> | :utilities:compileJava | 0.054s |
> | :app:startScripts | 0.049s |

Answer (score 6):

I created a plugin since [passy/build-time-tracker-plugin](https://github.com/passy/build-time-tracker-plugin) is no longer actively maintained. Mine prints ASCII bar charts too, and comes with customization options.

https://github.com/asarkar/build-time-tracker

```
== Build time summary ==
 :commons:extractIncludeProto | 4.000s | 14% | ████
       :commons:compileKotlin | 2.000s |  7% | ██
         :commons:compileJava | 6.000s | 21% | ██████
:service-client:compileKotlin | 1.000s |  4% | █
        :webapp:compileKotlin | 1.000s |  4% | █
     :webapp:dockerBuildImage | 4.000s | 14% | ████
      :webapp:dockerPushImage | 4.000s | 14% | ████
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with gradle 4.8.1 :( (yes I know I shouldn't use one that old but I don't make the decisions on the project)

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Feel free to open a GitHub ticket and attach a project that can be used to reproduce the problem. I won't promise to support an ancient Gradle version, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Simple sorting would make [@jlevy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438620/2911458) even better.
Also, for a typical production apps, I think the threshold of 50ms is too low.
We usually care about tasks that take more than X second.
**project/build.gradle**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

// Log timings per task.
class TimingsListener implements TaskExecutionListener, BuildListener {
    private long startTime
    private timings = []

    @Override
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime()
    }

    @Override
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState taskState) {
        def ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
        timings.add(new Tuple2<Integer, String>(ms, task.path))
        task.project.logger.warn "${task.path} took ${ms}ms"
    }

    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        println "Task timings:"
        def tmp = timings.toSorted(new Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, String>>() {
            @Override
            int compare(Tuple2<Integer, String> o, Tuple2<Integer, String> t1) {
                return o.first - t1.first
            }
        })
        for (timing in tmp) {
            if (timing.first >= 1000) {
                printf "%ss  %s\n", timing.first / 1000, timing.second
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void buildStarted(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void settingsEvaluated(Settings settings) {}
}

gradle.addListener new TimingsListener()
```

Terminal output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14m 33s
948 actionable tasks: 419 executed, 476 from cache, 53 up-to-date
Task timings:
1.036s  :cbl-config:mergeMyAppDebugResources
1.187s  :express:bundleMyAppDebug
1.199s  :country:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
1.214s  :core-for-test:extractMyAppDebugAnnotations
1.242s  :analytics:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
1.308s  :express:extractMyAppDebugAnnotations
1.33s  :availability:dataBindingExportBuildInfoMyAppDebug
1.357s  :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForMyAppDebug
1.405s  :hermes:generateMyAppDebugBuildConfig
1.56s  :availability:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
1.65s  :app:javaPreCompileMyAppDebugUnitTest
1.749s  :chat:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
1.858s  :cbl-config-for-test:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
2.027s  :cbl-config:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
2.056s  :analytics-for-test:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
2.447s  :crypto:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
2.45s  :crypto:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
2.47s  :chat:javaPreCompileMyAppDebugUnitTest
2.639s  :crypto-for-test:dataBindingExportBuildInfoMyAppDebug
2.683s  :test-utils:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
3.056s  :crypto:lintMyAppDebug
3.227s  :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForMyAppDebug
3.272s  :express:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
3.394s  :crypto:mergeMyAppDebugResources
3.426s  :core:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
4.299s  :multicity:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
4.333s  :app:packageMyAppDebug
4.584s  :availability-for-test:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
4.672s  :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForMyAppDebug
4.786s  :map:lintMyAppDebug
5.309s  :country:lintMyAppDebug
5.332s  :job:lintMyAppDebug
5.389s  :map:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
6.04s  :express:lintMyAppDebug
6.584s  :hermes:lintMyAppDebug
6.707s  :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyAppDebug
7.052s  :multicity:lintMyAppDebug
8.044s  :multicity:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
8.87s  :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForMyAppDebug
9.371s  :uikit:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
9.429s  :availability:lintMyAppDebug
13.12s  :app:compileMyAppDebugUnitTestKotlin
16.276s  :hermes:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
16.898s  :chat:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
17.174s  :job:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
36.008s  :aaefawef:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
96.88s  :app:compileMyAppDebugJavaWithJavac
125.693s  :app:lintMyAppDebug
145.538s  :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForMyAppDebug
182.752s  :app:testMyAppDebugUnitTest
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Gradle 4.8.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio version >= 4.0 added build analyzer, which track execution time per task in gradle.

Find here after success build:

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: Not everyone using Gradle is developing Android apps, not to mention this doesn't work when built from command line/CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with [@Jilevys solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438620/3060133) but was getting error in finding the class ***org.gradle.util.Clock()***

I have modified it to use Java8 classes. Put below code on top of the build.gradle

```
    import java.time.LocalDateTime

class TimingsListener implements TaskExecutionListener, BuildListener {
    private LocalDateTime taskStartTime

    @Override
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        taskStartTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @Override
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState taskState) {
        LocalDateTime taskEndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        def seconds = Duration.between(taskStartTime, taskEndTime).toSeconds();
        task.project.logger.warn "${task.path} took ${seconds} seconds."
    }

    @Override
    void buildStarted(Gradle gradle) {
        project.logger.warn "Build started on "+LocalDateTime.now()
    }

    @Override
    void settingsEvaluated(Settings settings) {

    }

    @Override
    void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {

    }

    @Override
    void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {

    }

    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        project.logger.warn "Build finished on "+LocalDateTime.now()

    }
}
gradle.addListener new TimingsListener()
```

It produces output similar to given below.

```
<projectname>:<taskName> took 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Or you could just [use a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051193/839733).

Comment: `No such property: project for class: TimingsListener` (gradle 4.8.1)