# how to fix a slow gradle clean build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Apologies for the very open nature of this question, but I have a java/spring-boot/gradle project and whenever I run `./gradlew clean build` it always takes so long to build (around 10 mins compared to ~1 min when other team members build the same projects on their laptops) - I've got no idea why this might be, so would anyone have any ideas of where to start/what information I would need to extract/analyse to find the cause of this problem (happy to post any requested info as an edit to the question).

Comment: don't clean just build, use the (remote) build cache, use parallel builds and make sure you have comparable hardware (cpu, memory etc).

Comment: I agree with the above comment as tools for speeding up the build. To find out what is taking so long, make a [build scan](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/) and check if there are any tasks that are taking longer than expected (like compilation, unit tests or assembly). If you are on Windows, it could also be Defender slowing everything down to a crawl.

Comment: Check that others might have excluded executing test cases (-xtest) while building in gradle

Answer (score 6):

**First**, in your gradle-wrapper.properties, add this:

```
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

and see if it helps. **It should.**

**Second**, you might want to implement a [TaskExecutionListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionListener.html) and register it with `gradle.taskGraph.addTaskExecutionListener`. The [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032086/4982691) comes from `Peter Niederwieser` himself.

In short, in your top-level `gradle.build`, copy this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class TimingsListener implements TaskExecutionListener, BuildListener {
    private long startTime
    private timings = []

    @Override
    void beforeExecute(Task task) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime()
    }

    @Override
    void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState taskState) {
        def ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        timings.add([ms, task.path])
        task.project.logger.warn "${task.path} took ${ms}ms"
    }

    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        println "Task timings:"
        for (timing in timings) {
            if (timing[0] >= 50) {
                printf "%7sms  %s\n", timing
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void buildStarted(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsEvaluated(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {}

    @Override
    void settingsEvaluated(Settings settings) {}
}

gradle.addListener new TimingsListener()
```

And the output might look like:

```
gradlew build

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava took 3255ms

> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
:processResources took 10ms

> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
:classes took 0ms

> Task :bootWar UP-TO-DATE
:bootWar took 637ms

> Task :war SKIPPED
:war took 0ms

> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
:assemble took 0ms

> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava took 427ms

> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources took 5ms

> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses took 0ms

> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
:test took 62ms

> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
:check took 0ms

> Task :build UP-TO-DATE
:build took 0ms
Task timings:
   3255ms  :compileJava
    637ms  :bootWar
    427ms  :compileTestJava
     62ms  :test
```

## BONUS

You can also speed up your tests by having [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/performance.html) in your build.gradle:

```
test {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1 
}
```

*Note that if you do run the tests in parallel, you will have to ensure that they are independent, i.e. don’t share resources, be that files, databases or something else. Otherwise there is a chance that the tests will interfere with each other in random and unpredictable ways.*

Comment: awesome tips man!

Comment: I have a little over 1000 tests. The Junit test reports show that these tests run in under 30 seconds for the tests themselves. Running them in IDE runs in 30 seconds. Why is gradlew taking 4 minutes to run the tests? I've tried running in parallel and am saving maybe 30-60 seconds tops. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running the task? It's possible that besides running the tests, it's doing something else as well. Probably enabling debug or so, will allow you to identify the culprit.